# how to write this equation in TensorFlow2? (4x+2 = 0)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

This code does not run in TensorFlow 2 what is the code?

```
import tensorflow as tf

# the equation is  : 4x+2 = 0
unknownvalue = tf.Variable(0.0)
a = tf.constant(4.0)
b = tf.constant(2.0)
c = tf.multiply(unknownvalue,a)  # 4x
equation  = tf.add(c,b) # 4x+2
zerovalue = tf.constant(0.0)
diff = tf.square(equation-zerovalue) # differnce is : 4x+2  -  0 
solving = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(diff)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TF2 changed the way to build training loops since TF1.
I encourage you to read this guide : [Writing a training loop from scratch](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch?hl=en), to learn a bit more how to do so.

Here is a straightforward implementation in TF2 of your tf1 code :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(0.0)
optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(1e-2)
for idx in range(1,26):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # the equation is  : 4x+2 = 0
        equation  = x*4 + 2 # 4x+2
        loss = tf.square(equation)
    grad = tape.gradient(loss, [x])
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad, [x]))
    if not idx%5:
         tf.print(f"Iteration:{idx},loss:{loss:.4f},x:{x.numpy():.4f}")
```

That results in

```
Iteration:5,loss:0.1829,x:-0.4273
Iteration:10,loss:0.0039,x:-0.4894
Iteration:15,loss:0.0001,x:-0.4985
Iteration:20,loss:0.0000,x:-0.4998
Iteration:25,loss:0.0000,x:-0.5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 2 code is much more simple and intuitive (except may be the GradientTape part, if you are not used to it):

```
import tensorflow as tf

# the equation is  : 4x+2 = 0
unknownvalue = tf.Variable(0.0)
with tf.GradientTape as tape:
    diff = (4 * unknownvalue + 2 - 0) ** 2
grads = tape.gradient(diff, unknownvalue)
tf.optimizers.SGD(0.01).apply_gradients(zip(grads, [unknownvalue])
```